# Woocommerce Custom Email path in Plugin

Tags: email, templates, woocommerce, orders

I create a custom order status and the . also cerated a custom email that are fired manually when the status is changed to my new custom status.

It works 100% if my custom email template reside in plugins/woocommerce/
`\plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/logistics-eft-paid.php`

But i need to add the custom email to my childtheme.
`themes/ms-store/woocommerce/emails/logistics-eft-paid.php`

I used this plugin, and I realise that `woocommerce_get_template` is outdated and replaced by `wc_get_template`, but is simply can't get it to work.

Even if I can hardcode the path to the email template, it will be a start.

Plugin used:
https://github.com/skyverge/woocommerce-expedited-order-email

Any help will be appreciated,

Thank you.